# PyAutoGUI "PixelMatchesColor" always TRUE

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to check a pixel on my screen using pyautogui "PixelMatchesColor" function, but it always runs the code even if the pixel color is not correct.

Here's my code:

```
def myFunction():
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    color = im.getpixel((1992, 1435))
    print(color)
    try:
        pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(1992, 1435, (85, 214, 142))
        print("Color found")
    except:
        print("Color not found")
```

Output:

```
(16, 52, 154)
Color found
```

Do you know where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#pixel-matching, `pixelMatchesColor` returns a boolean value `True` or `False` to indicate whether the color matches.

To branch on a boolean value, use an `if` statement. A `try` statement is for catching exceptions, which is not relevant here.

```
if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(1992, 1435, (85, 214, 142)):
    print("Color found")
else:
    print("Color not found")
```